# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.9

I just installed `Magento 2.1.9 on CentOS 7.4.`  I have configured MySql 5.7.17.  I am using the web-based Setup Wizard.

On the step for 'Add a Database' I get the error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied

My `MySql` server is on a separate host from my Magento2.  I am able to connect to the MySql server using command line from the Magento2 server.

**How can I get past this error in the web-based Setup Wizard?**

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for magento@%                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'magento'@'%'                  |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `magento`.* TO 'magento'@'%' |
+------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Database and user which you are using is having all rights on database ?

Comment: Yes.  I have updated the original post with the details of privileges.  The user has all privileges.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44092808/7472487
check this post once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the SELinux security policies.

By default, the policy httpd_can_network_connect_db is disabled (meaning that your web server cannot contact a remote DB.)

You can check this using:

> getsebool -a | grep httpd

in case `httpd_can_network_connect_db` is Off, then you can enable using:

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1